# How to pass object to a new Activity? (how to inject)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I want to pass an object (not data!) that implements some interface (ex. IConnect ) to a new Activity.
Activity will call some methods from this object to acquire data.

How to do that? (Serializable and Parcelable are for objects/data/structures i guess, not for objects/interfaces that 'DO' something).

Should I pass a class name in Intent extras? and then Activity will create desired object?
How to inject an object (a few different classes that implements IConnect) to a new Activity ?

Answer (score 4):

### MyParcelable.java

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable { 

    private String mVal; 

    public MyParcelable(String val) { 
        mVal = val; 
    } 

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR = 
        new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() { 
        public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) { 
            String s = in.readString(); 
            return new MyParcelable(s); 
        } 

        public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) { 
            return new MyParcelable[size]; 
        } 
    }; 

    public String getValue() { 
        return mVal; 
    } 

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel p) { 
        p.writeString(mVal); 
    } 

    public String toString() { 
        return "MyParcelable[val=" + mVal + "]"; 
    } 

}
```

---

### SendParcelable.java

```
public class SendParcelable extends Activity { 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
        super.onCreate(icicle); 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReceiveParcelable.class); 
        Parcelable p = new MyParcelable("test"); 
        intent.putExtra("myparcelable", p); 
        Log.i("ParcelDemo", "Sending Parcelable"); 
        startActivity(intent); 
    } 
}
```

---

### ReceiveParcelable.java

```
public class ReceiveParcelable extends Activity { 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
      super.onCreate(icicle); 
      Intent intent = getIntent(); 
       Parcelable p = intent.getParcelableExtra("myparcelable"); 
        Log.i("ParcelDemo", "Got Parcelable " + p); 
        if (p != null && p instanceof MyParcelable && 
            ((MyParcelable) p).getValue().equals("test")) { 
            Log.i("ParcelDemo", "Success!"); 
        } else { 
            Log.i("ParcelDemo", "Failure!"); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive example :)
For now, i decided to use:     


 String className = getIntent().getStringExtra("com.myproject.ModelClass");
    IModel model = (IModel)Class.forName(className).newInstance();

Answer (score 1):

There is an entry in Android documentation - [How do I pass data between Activities/Services within a single application?](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html#3) If you're talking about non-persistent objects, your options will be:

- Singleton class
- A public static field/method
- A HashMap of WeakReferences to Objects

By the way, I don't really understand the distinction you make between objects and data. An object contains fields and a set of methods to work with them. However, it doesn't matter if this object has some methods or not, they do not make a part of its state. If you pass an object, you only need to pass its state, so you can save the state using serialization (through Serializable or Parcelable interface) and then restore it.

Comment: but i don't want to pass data (i know how to use bundles/parcels).
I want to pass object that implements some interface and that DO something (like connecting to internet/other resources depending on implementation)

Comment: Why do you want to pass an object which contains no data? Create a new one instead then. If it really has no internal state, then it will operate as good as the old one.

Comment: because this object DO something, it implements some interface

Comment: What do you mean, do? It has methods? Or is it in the middle of doing something?

Comment: it has methods that have some logic to do.
I could use a Factory with parameters in an Activity or just create a new object from class name (i've posted a reply)

Comment: So you went with creating a new object after all. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to find a way to pass objects between activities you can override the Application class.

Way to use application class.

Extend the application class and add your object as its attribute. In any activity, if you call the below code, it will return a singleton.

```
MyApplication appContext = (MyApplication) getApplication();
```

To make this work you need to add this to the application tag of the manifest file

```
 android:name=".MyApplication"
```

This method is used to pass values and objects around the app.

Answer (score 0):

Parcelable is an option. It will write the data from your object and create a new object from the data. Its like saving and loading data.

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html to see how you should implement it.

Answer (score 0):

For now, i did for destination Activity:

```
    String className = getIntent().getStringExtra("com.myproject.ModelClass");
    IModel model = (IModel)Class.forName(className).newInstance();
```

And i have a specific implementaction in the Activity.