# How do I pass an object between activities?

Tags: android, list, android-intent

ALL,

Consider the following data structure:

```
class Foo
{
private int m1;
private double m2;
};

class Bar
{
private int m1;
private List<Foo> m2;
};
```

Now what I want to do is to pass Bar::m2 from one activity to another.
The data in Bar are in the list view and selecting the row I need to pass an appropriate list m2 structure.

What is the best way to do it?
What I tried is this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra( "test", new ArrayList<Foo> );
```

but the receiving intent throws an exception "Parcelable: Unable to marshall"

AFAICT ArrayList should be serializable, so I don't understand why I'm getting an exception.

Can someone sched some light here please?

Thank you.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html `List` is not serializable, and the method `putExtra` on intent takes a `List` not an `ArrayList` so your ArrayList is taken as it's interface `List`

Comment: There's so many dups of this I'm having a hard time choosing.

Comment: Dup? [How to pass object to a new Activity? (how to inject)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725840/how-to-pass-object-to-a-new-activity-how-to-inject?rq=1) (was first Related question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AFAICT ArrayList should be serializable

Yes, but you don't have an `ArrayList` of nothing -- you have an `ArrayList` of `Foo` objects.

> I don't understand why I'm getting an exception

Because `Foo` is not `Serializable`.

The efficient answer is for you to implement `Parcelable` support on `Foo`, then use `putParcelableArrayListExtra()` on your `Intent`.

The less-programming answer is for you to implement `Serializable` on `Foo`, in which case your current `putExra()` should work.

Comment: Well apparently I was too fast to accept it. ;-) I did add Parcelable to Foo and then used put/getParcelableArrayListExtra(). However, I still receive "Unmarshalling unknown type code". Any idea?

Comment: @Igor: All I can suggest is for you to post your `Foo` implementation and the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your custom objects Seriablizable.  Here is the documentation

[Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("object", yourobject);
startActivity(new Intent(this,Myclass.class).putExtras(bundle);
```

your object class should implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.

```
class Foo implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int m1;
    private double m2;
};

class Bar implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int m1;
    private List<Foo> m2;
};
```